# Deleting duplicates in a vector filled with a pair of two ints

Tags: c++

I am having trouble running through a vector of two int pairs and deleting all the duplicates. Right now the vector looks like this:

```
3, 2
3, 2
3, 2
5, 3
5, 3
```

And it goes on. I want it to looks like this:

```
3, 2 
5, 3
```

Here is my code:

```
sort(vec3.begin(), vec3.end());
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec4;
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<vec3.size(); i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j<vec3.size(); j++){
        if(vec3[i] != vec3[j]){
            vec4.push_back(vec3[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    cout << vec4[i].first << ", " << vec4[i].second << endl;
}
```

What I did is I sorted the first vector, which worked, and then I am trying to run through it where after `vec3(i) != vec3(j)` it breaks out of the inner loops and adds `vec3(i)` only once to a new vector, essentially deleting the other duplicates. However, this is not working. It is taking forever to run, and I think it has to do with my break not working.

Comment: FWIW, [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in conjunction with a call to `erase` will do this for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Awesome I just tried it is so much more simple than what I was doing and it worked! Thank you

Comment: You might want to still `std::sort` before using `std::unique`, I'm pretty sure `std::unique` only removes adjacent identical elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not really handling the duplicates correctly at all.

Lets look at the logic using your example:

- The outer loop starts at `vec3[0]`. It sees the 1st `3, 2`, then the inner loop scans for the next non-duplicate, finding the 1st `5, 3`, and so it adds `3, 2` to `vec4`.
- Then the outer loop moves on to `vec3[1]`. It sees the 2nd `3, 2`, then the inner loop scans for the next non-duplicate, finding the 1st `5, 3` again, and so it adds `3, 2` to `vec4` again.
- Then the outer loop moves on to `vec3[2]`. It sees the 3rd `3, 2`, then the inner loop scans for the next non-duplicate, finding the 1st `5, 3` again, and so it adds `3, 2` to `vec4` again.
- Then the outer loop moves on to `vec3[3]`. It sees the 1st `5, 3`, then the inner loop scans for the next non-duplicate, finding none, and so it does not add `5, 3` to `vec4`.
- Then the outer loop moves on to `vec3[4]`. It sees the 2nd `5, 3`, then the inner loop scans for the next non-duplicate, finding none, and so it does not add `5, 3` to `vec4`.

See the problem?

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
std::sort(vec3.begin(), vec3.end());
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec4;

size_t i = 0;
while (i < vec3.size()) {
    vec4.push_back(vec3[i]);
    // skip any duplicates
    while ((++i < vec3.size()) && (vec3[i] == vec3[i-1]));
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < vec4.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec4[i].first << ", " << vec4[i].second << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HQU0Zi)

Which can be greatly simplified using [`std::unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) with [`vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), eg:

```cpp
std::sort(vec3.begin(), vec3.end());
vec3.erase(
    std::unique(vec3.begin(), vec3.end()),
    vec3.end()
);

for(size_t i = 0; i < vec3.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec3[i].first << ", " << vec3[i].second << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/wbW2xQ)